# inserting an integer at the beginning of an array MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mips32

what would be the way to go about inserting an integer at the beginning of an array?

Example:

register $s0 = 4 (# of elements in array)

register $s1 = 0x10040000 (address of the beginning of array)

```
0x10040000 10
0x10040004 20
0x10040008 30
0x1000400C 40
```

I want to insert an int, say 5 at 0x10040000 and move everything down:

```
0x10040000 5
0x10040004 10
0x10040008 20
0x1000400C 30
0x10004010 40
```

One way I was able to do it is to insert 5 at the address before the array but what I would like to be able to do is insert 5 at the beginning of the array and move everything else down

Comment: Well, if you stop thinking about it as an array, and just look at the two "memory images", it's sort of obvious what has to be done. You need to move the memory content 4 bytes up (4 words from `0x10040000`) and then write the `5` to the `0x10040000`. This kind of `memmove`, to be done in optimal way, is usually very CPU specific (not sure about MIPS), but when performance is not an issue, you just do `i=4; while (i--) array[i+1] = array[i];` (going from array end, so you don't overwrite the original values by the moved ones).

Comment: BTW, this is the reason why C++ `vector<>` is believed to be "slow" for insertions, because you always need to move remaining part of array to create empty slot inside the continuous storage, but the computers love to work with continuous well packed data structures, so often this insertion penalty is quickly regained in further processing, so don't underestimate power of `vector<>` structures, and rather than guessing use profiling, to find the real performance. `vector<>` type of data structures is usually a best start for initial version.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a loop and a temp register (`$s0`) to shift the value:

```
.data
N: .word 3
VET: .word 2, 3, 4, 5

.text
li $t1, 0 
lw $t0, N
sll $t0, $t0, 2
la $t2, $t0(VET)
srl $t0, $t0, 2
loop:
blt $t0, $t1 end_loop
lw $s0, ($t2) #load the number from i pos
sw $s0, 4($t2) #store the number in i+1 pos
addi $t2, $t2, -4 #i--
addi $t0, $t0, -1
j loop
end_loop:
li $s0, 1 #load value you want to store
sw $s0, VET #store value
lw $t0, N
add $t0, $t0, 1 
sw $t0, N #update value of N
```

Now the value `1` is at the beginning of your vector.
It's not optimized, it's just to let you understand the logic behind the program. Hope this can be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You will need an inner and an outer loop.

```
.data
Array: .word 3 5 1 90 21 11 2
.text 
la $a0,Array
addi $a1,$zero,7 
jal InsertSort

li $v0,10
syscall

InserSort:
addi $t0,$zero,1
outerloop:
beq $t0,$a1,finish

sll $t4,$t0,2
add $t4,$t4,$a0
lw $t4,0($t4)

addi $t1,$t0,-1
innerloop:
slt $t2,$t1,$zero
bne $t2,$zero,GoOuter

sll $t3,$t1,2
add $t3,$t3,$a0
lw t3,0($t3)
slt $t5,$t3,$t4
bne $t5,$zero,GoOuter

addi $t6,$t1,1
sll $t6,$t6,2
add $t6,$t6,$a0
sw $t3,0($t6)
addi $t1,$t1,-1
j innerloop

GoOuter:

addi $t8,$t1,1
sll $t8,$t8,2
add $t8,$t8,$a0
sw $t4,0($t8)
addi $t0,$t0,1
j outerloop

finish:
jr $ra
```

Comment: Please use code-formatting (triple backticks) for your code.  It's also good coding style to indent the instructions one level relative to the labels.  It's also good to indent the operands to a consistent column, so mnemonics of different length don't make things ragged.  That makes it easier to see which registers are involved between different instructions.  Also, a good Stack Overflow answer will comment the code pretty thoroughly to explain why / how it works.

Comment: This question isn't asking for InsertionSort, it's asking how to do one insert at a specified position.  Like C++ `std::vector<int>::insert(pos, value)` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)